# Node.js Variations in runtime when using the same input

Tags: node.js, algorithm

I have a Node.js application (also using Express) which iterates through a large chunk of JSON-data.
Roughly, the client presses a button which calls a route in my back end. My application then receives some id's and fetches the data from another external API. **After** receiving the data, I've created a Date-object. Then I iterate through the data and after the iteration is done, I create another Date-object, and log the time variation between the two to measure the time spent iterating.

1. 1st button press: 100ms.
2. 2nd button press: 46ms.
3. 3rd button press: 42ms.
4. 4th button press: 44ms.

The iteration time always stays between 40-55ms after the first.
If I restart my server and repeat the process, the first iteration time is back to +- 100ms, and the rest is back to 40-55ms.

I'm really not sure why I get such a large variation in runtime only on the first iteration, but I'm guessing there might be some caching happening behind the scenes that I'm not aware of.

**BONUS** I want to do multiple tests of different sizes of data to measure the complexity of the algorithm I've written, but I'm not sure whether this is the best approach. Note that I'm not concerned with how long it takes to fetch the data, only the time it takes to iterate through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more thorough research on how code is complied in Node.js (V8-engine), I found that the V8-engine uses JIT (Just-In-Time) compiling.

In relation to the question, the first time the button gets pressed, the code responsible for handling the data set gets compiled during runtime. The next time the button gets pressed the code is already compiled since it's happening in the same runtime => therefore variations in iteration time q.e.d.